# RDP Terminal Chooser

Tags: networking, remote-desktop, rdp

Is there any software for linux or windows that lets you connect to a certain port over rdp, and then have it present a gui to you with multiple choices of servers to connect to, so that when you select one of them, it opens a new rdp session to said host?

Comment: I probably shouldn't reward you for asking an off-topic question, but...  Are you asking for yourself as an admin, or for users.   For admins, get http://www.mremoteng.org/

Comment: apt-get install rdesktop + fluxbox

Answer (score 0):

There is [Remote Desktop Gateway](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows7/what-is-a-remote-desktop-gateway-server) server which is included with Server 2008 and latter in addition to Windows Home Server.